# Выезд блока до середины

Tags: jquery

Сейчас блок выезжает до левого края, затем доезжает до правого.
Нужно, чтобы он выезжал до середины и уезжал полностью обратно вправо.
Не могу найти, где я накосячил?

```js
$("body").on("click", ".hamburger", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).find('.first').toggleClass("openfirst");
  $(this).find('.third').toggleClass("openthird");

  var $marginLefty = $(this).next();
  var $dlinna = $marginLefty.outerWidth();
  console.log(parseInt($marginLefty.css('marginLeft'), 10));

  $marginLefty.animate({
    marginLeft: parseInt($marginLefty.css('marginLeft'), 10) == 0 ? $dlinna : 0
  });

});
```

```css
.inner {
  width: 50%;
  height: 30px;
  margin-left: 1000px;
  background: #ccc;
  transition: 0.4s;
}
/*--------------*/

.hamburger {
  width: 26px;
  float: right
}
.navicon {
  background: grey;
  display: block;
  height: 1px;
  position: relative;
  //transition: background .2s ease-out;
  width: 21px;
  margin: 3px;
  transition: 0.2s;
}
.openfirst {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.openthird {
  margin-top: 5px;
}
.wrapper {
  width: 500px;
  height: 250px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="hamburger"><span class="navicon first"></span><span class="navicon"></span><span class="navicon third"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

Ссылка на [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nytrx8vr/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Исправьте код

```
$marginLefty.animate({
    marginLeft: parseInt($marginLefty.css('marginLeft'),10) == 0 ? $dlinna : 0
});
```

На

```
$marginLefty.animate({
    marginLeft: parseInt($marginLefty.css('marginLeft'), 10) == 1000 ? ($dlinna / 2) : 1000
});
```

```js
$("body").on("click", ".hamburger", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).find('.first').toggleClass("openfirst");
  $(this).find('.third').toggleClass("openthird");

  var $marginLefty = $(this).next();
  var $dlinna = $marginLefty.outerWidth();
  console.log(parseInt($marginLefty.css('marginLeft'), 10));

  $marginLefty.animate({
    marginLeft: parseInt($marginLefty.css('marginLeft'), 10) == 1000 ? ($dlinna / 2) : 1000
  });

});
```

```css
.inner {
  width: 50%;
  height: 30px;
  margin-left: 1000px;
  background: #ccc;
  transition: 0.4s;
}
/*--------------*/

.hamburger {
  width: 26px;
  float: right
}
.navicon {
  background: grey;
  display: block;
  height: 1px;
  position: relative;
  //transition: background .2s ease-out;
  width: 21px;
  margin: 3px;
  transition: 0.2s;
}
.openfirst {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.openthird {
  margin-top: 5px;
}
.wrapper {
  width: 500px;
  height: 250px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="hamburger"><span class="navicon first"></span><span class="navicon"></span><span class="navicon third"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

В тернарном операторе некорректная проверка, к примеру если len == 0 то и делать его нулевым?

```
var len = parseInt($marginLefty.css('marginLeft'),10);
marginLeft: len == 0 ? len : 0
```

Так работает: https://jsfiddle.net/5jaug7ju/

html

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="hamburger">
   <span class="navicon first"></span>
   <span class="navicon"></span>
   <span class="navicon third"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

JS

```
 $("body").on("click", ".hamburger", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
  $(this).find('.first').toggleClass("openfirst");
 $(this).find('.third').toggleClass("openthird");

    var $marginLefty = $(this).next();
      var $dlinna= $marginLefty.outerWidth();
      console.log('dlinna ' + $dlinna);
      var len = parseInt($marginLefty.css('marginLeft'),10);
      console.log('len '+len);
        $marginLefty.animate({
            marginLeft: len == 0 ? 1000 : 0

        });
   len = parseInt($marginLefty.css('marginLeft'),10);
      console.log('len '+len); 
    });
```

CSS

```
 .inner
    {
        width: 50%;
        height: 30px;
        margin-left: 1000px;
        background: #ccc;

    /*transition:0.4s;*/

        }
    /*--------------*/
    .hamburger{width: 26px;float:right}

 .navicon {
  background: grey;
  display: block;
  height: 1px;
  position: relative;
  //transition: background .2s ease-out;
  width: 21px;
  margin:3px;
  transition:0.2s;

}

.openfirst{
  margin-bottom:5px;
}

.openthird{
  margin-top:5px;
}
.wrapper{
  width:500px;
  height:250px;
  border:1px solid grey;

}
```